# Firebase Storage pictures do not load when no internet connectivity

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, alamofire, firebase-storage

So when I have persistence enabled in my Swift app, I realize that when I enter the app in Airplane mode (no internet connectivity), other pictures that are loaded from other sources such as Facebook (i.e. https://www.facebook.com/picturefromfacebook.png) could still load. However, pictures from my Firebase Storage URL did not load, with this error code:

> FAILURE: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x1746412c0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1009 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=50, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/app-abdf9.appspot.com/o/real_db%2Fuser%2FILzu2nUGdVZQ06MFhcAd3rmyvaM2%2Fprofile_photo?alt=media&token=1ce9b3b7-2884-4429-9a03-1632d10a7251, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/app-abdf9.appspot.com/o/real_db%2Fuser%2FILzu2nUGdVZQ06MFhcAd3rmyvaM2%2Fprofile_photo?alt=media&token=1ce9b3b7-2884-4429-9a03-1632d10a7251, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=50, NSLocalizedDescription=The Internet connection appears to be offline.}

Why do other pictures get cached offline, but not Firebase Storage's?

My initial guess is that the token in the URL for the Firebase Storage is causing download issues when there is no internet connectivity. Is there a workaround? By the way I am using AlamofireImage's af_setImage to download and cache the images.

Comment: Are all the image loads happening through the exact same API calls?  If not, could there be some differences in the way those APIs cache images?  If not, do you think maybe images from difference sources have different caching directives from the respective services?

Comment: Yes they are all being cached the same way. My gut feel is that the token in the Firebase Storage image url is causing issues when there is no internet connectivity.

Comment: My gut feeling is that the `cache-control` header is set to aggressively cache Facebook (and other) photos, while it's likely not set on the Firebase image. Set the `cacheControl` metadata property to something reasonable and try the experiment again.

Comment: Forgot to mention I use AlamofireImage's setImage to cache and set the image

Comment: @MikeMcDonald May I ask how to set the cache-control metadata property? Do I just set it in the Firebase url?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/file-metadata#update_file_metadata @solistice

Comment: @MikeMcDonald Thanks so much! That solved it :) Also question: If i set an image as "public" does it automatically cache it?

Comment: In your security rules? No, security rules have nothing to do with current caching.